# Objects not loading in tableview

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, swift3

So I'm using a pfquerytableview controller and loading objects in my tableview but the problem is that I get an error that " a long operation is occurring on the main thread". So what I did was I changed my load objects function. Here it is and when I change it, no objects load in my tableview when I try to load the objects in background which I thought would be the solution to the main thread issue. Here is the code.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
    var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!
        query = PFQuery(className: "query")
        query.limit = 25
        query.skip = 25

    return query
}
override func loadObjects() -> BFTask<NSArray> {
    return queryForTable().findObjectsInBackground()
}
```